# One Controller Multiple Tables

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am working on a form that needs to be able to update two different tables.
I am using the Order controller and need to update the order table. The other table I need to update is CampaignCustomers, where I would like to update the campaignID.

The two Models are associated, and here is the result when I debug $order:

```
array(
    'Order' => array(
        'OrderID' => (int) 1574996,
        'OrderType' => '3',
        'UPSTrackingNumber' => null,
        'CreatedDate' => 'Mar 30 2019 12:42:00:000PM',
        'ShippedOnDate' => null,
        'Notes' => null,
        'OrderedBy' => 'TIM',
        'UserID' => (int) 431,
        'CampaignCustomerID' => (float) 78156512,
        'TaxPercentage' => (int) 0,
        'DiscountID' => null,
        'DiscountPercentage' => (int) 8,
        'TotalPrice' => (float) 7.75,
        'OrderStatusID' => (int) 13,
        'LabelCategory' => null,
        'LabelPrinted' => (int) 0,
        'InvoicePrinted' => (int) 0,
        'ShippingMethodID' => (int) 9,
        'SaturdayDelivery' => (int) 0,
        'ShippingAddress' => 'ert',
        'ShippingPrice' => (float) 7.75,
        'ConfirmationEmail' => null,
        'PaymentMethod' => 'Bill In Full',
        'PurchaseOrderNumber' => ' dfqsdfsdafe3r23rwererewrw',
        'CreditCardHolderName' => null,
        'CreditCardNumber' => null,
        'CreditCardExpirationDate' => null,
        'CreditCardStreet' => null,
        'CreditCardZipCode' => null,
        'CreditCardCVV' => null,
        'TransactionID' => null
    ),

    'CampaignCustomer' => array(
        'CampaignCustomerID' => (float) 78156512,
        'CampaignID' => (int) 422,
        'CustomerID' => (int) 3633
    ),
```

This is my view:

```
<?php
debug($order);
echo $this->Html->div("box");
    echo $this->Html->tag("h3","Edit Order ".$order['Order']['OrderID']);
        echo "<p><b>Company: </b>" . $order["Company"]["CompanyName"] . "</p>";
        echo "<p><b>Order ID: </b>" . $order["Order"]["OrderID"] . "</p>";
    echo $this->Form->create(("Order"));
            echo $this->Form->input("PurchaseOrderNumber");
            echo $this->Form->input("CampaignID",array("options"=>$campaigns,"label"=>"Campaign","selected"=>$order["Campaign"]["CampaignID"]));
            echo $this->Form->input("CreatedDate");
            echo $this->Form->input("OrderType",array("options"=>$orderType,"selected"=>$order["Order"]["OrderType"]));
            echo $this->Form->input("OrderedBy");
            echo $this->Form->input("ShippingMethodID",array("options"=>$shipping_method_ids,"selected"=>$order["Order"]["ShippingMethodID"],"label"=>"Shipping Method"));
            echo $this->Form->input("SaturdayDelivery");
            echo $this->Form->input("UserID",array("options"=>$users,"selected"=>$order["Order"]["UserID"],"label"=>"Sales Agent"));
            echo $this->Form->input("DiscountPercentage");
            echo $this->Form->input("ShippingAddress");
    echo $this->Form->end("Update Order");
echo "</div>";
?>
```

The only thing that won't update is the CampaignID field, because it is a different table.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've not passed  the `CampaignCustomer` data in your form, so when the post request is made, there's nothing for it to update in terms of `CampaignCustomer`

You need to include this information in your form in either hidden fields or visible ones to ensure it gets updated.

```
 echo $this->Form->create();
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.PurchaseOrderNumber");
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.CampaignID",array("options"=>$campaigns,"label"=>"Campaign","selected"=>$order["Campaign"]["CampaignID"]));
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.CreatedDate");
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.rderType",array("options"=>$orderType,"selected"=>$order["Order"]["OrderType"]));
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.OrderedBy");
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.ShippingMethodID",array("options"=>$shipping_method_ids,"selected"=>$order["Order"]["ShippingMethodID"],"label"=>"Shipping Method"));
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.SaturdayDelivery");
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.UserID",array("options"=>$users,"selected"=>$order["Order"]["UserID"],"label"=>"Sales Agent"));
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.DiscountPercentage");
        echo $this->Form->input("Order.ShippingAddress");
        echo $this->Form->input("CampaignCustomer.CampaignCustomerID");
        echo $this->Form->input("CampaignCustomer.CampaignID");
        echo $this->Form->input("CampaignCustomer.CustomerID");
 echo $this->Form->end("Update Order");
```